# Core Plot header path error

Tags: objective-c, ios

Lexical or Preprocessor issue.

I have been trying to add core plot to my project but I keep getting met with the above error. I have added the path to the header search paths in the build settings. and have set it to recursive. but still no joy.

/Users/User/Desktop/CorePlotDemo/CorePlot_0.4/Source/framework

Is there something else I have to do to add a header file to the project.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the list that works for me:

- Add the CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj to your own project
- Add the location of the framework to the header search path
- ensure the header search path is recursive
- add `-ObjC` to the Other Linker Flags
- add #import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h" to your source
- build the CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj
- under `Build phases` of *your own* target add `libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a` under `Link Binary With Library`
- build your own target

Comment: Thanks for the post. i have done what you have written but I'm still getting a red error saying the #import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h" can't be found. Ill keep at it.

Comment: just out of interest what version of the compiler are you using and are you using ARC?

Comment: I use  LLVM and no ARC. When you open a Terminal and do a `ls -d /Users/User/Desktop/CorePlotDemo/CorePlot_0.4/Source/framework`, do you see a line returned with the directory? And a  `ls /Users/User/Desktop/CorePlotDemo/CorePlot_0.4/Source/framework/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h` finds the h-file? No spaces in the directory names?